# WhatsApp Business - Cloud API 'Single Product message API' giving error as a product not found, even product is existing in catalogue

Tags: chatbot, whatsapp

I am testing the Single Product Message API endpoint in Whatsapp-Business Cloud.

It is working for some of the products in the catalogue, but for some other products in the same catalogue giving error as 'product not found for product_retailer_id, XX, in catalog_id, XXXXXXXXX'

I can't see any Issue / Policy violations for those products.

This is the Sample Request Payload

```
{
    "messaging_product": "whatsapp",
    "recipient_type": "individual",
    "to": "XXXX",
    "type": "interactive",
    "interactive": {
        "type": "product",
        "body": {
            "text": "Hello 111111"
        },
        "footer": {
            "text": "Hello1 1111111"
        },
        "action": {
            "catalog_id": "XXXX",
            "product_retailer_id": "XX"
        }
    }
 }
```

can you please help me to resolve this issue

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. My `catalog_id` and `product_retailer_id` is valid, but somehow still do not work. Then I submit a ticket to FB direct support, and after a couple of seconds suddenly it works. I haven't gotten any response from direct support yet. Maybe after registering the catalog and connecting the catalog to a WhatsApp number, we need to wait for some time.

Here is my json payload

```
{
  "messaging_product": "whatsapp",
  "recipient_type": "individual",
  "to": "6289XXX055XXX",
  "type": "interactive",
  "interactive": {
    "type": "product",
    "body": {
      "text": "Indomie"
    },
    "footer": {
      "text": "Indomie rasa soto"
    },
    "action": {
      "catalog_id": "553992496785XXX",
      "product_retailer_id": "indomie-soto"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the error arises because when importing the data feed, the product has a column that should be filled in but has not been filled in, so even though it has successfully entered the catalog, there is still a related issue (even though it has been corrected by editing the item, it still fails to be accessed via the cloud API)